# How to save a newly created pdf file using SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I am creating a pdf file using `itextsharp` and saving it on my local disk by giving hard coded path which I dont like.

I want to give users the facility to select the path where they want to save it. I tried to do it using `SaveFaileDialog` but was not able to get it.

Here is my code :

```
//Exporting to PDF
string folderPath = "C://PDFs//";
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A1, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    stream.Close();
 }
```

I am not getting how to add `savefileDialog` box code in it.

Please help me .

SaveFileDialog box code..

```
using (SaveFileDialog exportSaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    exportSaveFileDialog.Title = "Select PDFFile";
    exportSaveFileDialog.Filter = "PDF(*.pdf)|*.pdf";

    if (DialogResult.OK == exportSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have u tried a code with `SaveFileDialog`. If yes, what problem are you facing?

Comment: "I tried to do it using SaveFaileDialog but not able to get it." Please show the code where you tried it and which error you get!

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Please see my updated post I am trying to use this code but not getting where to put in.

Comment: @user3816352: What do you do inside if statement?

Comment: @DatRid Please see my updated post with SaveFileDialogue  .I am not getting how to use this in my code.

Comment: @user3816352 When you post/update your question, please always have a look to the code format. Thanks!

Comment: @user3816352: Use your file stream code inside if statement of SaveFileDialog and give the path of FileStream provided by SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below mentioned code:

```
SaveFileDialog svg = new SaveFileDialog();
svg.ShowDialog();

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream( svg.FileName+ ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A1, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: It Worked !!.Thanks One more clarification If i need to add messagebox after pdf creation Where i have to that and how..

Comment: After stream.Close() you can set the MessageBox.Show("File Created on "+svg.FileName+ ".pdf");

Comment: I think its better to have `if(svg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` and you don't need `stream.Close();` it will be closed automatically because of the using...